# css align text with icon with

Tags: css, text, icons, alignment

I want to align icon with text, view like screenshot below :

here's html source :

```
<a class="download" href="#">'.$dicon.'Download : ca dmv driving performance evaluation score sheet PDF</a>
```

here's `$dicon` source :

```
$dicon = '<img src="icon.png" width="25">';
```

here's css source :

```
.download{
        display:block;
        font-family:opensansitalic;
        text-transform: uppercase;
        vertical-align:baseline;
    }
```

Result:

[image]

Is my code wrong or anyway to fix it will be helpful.

Comment: Please put on a code snippet and explain your problem/error.

Comment: @MrLister yes, it run on php file. i'm sorry i cant add screenshot because im in low reputation.

Comment: @MrLister here's the screenshot http://prntscr.com/6qaajp

Comment: @amine250 : https://jsfiddle.net/cindraonggo/h5meqf3j/ 
the problem is i cant align icon and text

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, I assume you want something like this?

[image]

If so, all you need is to `vertical-align` img to the middle.

```
.download img {vertical-align:middle;}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MrLister/dp08z9jb/)

The problem is that by default, images have vertical-align:baseline, that is, they are lined out with their bottom to the baseline of the text. With this one, they are aligned with their center to the center of the text. See also http://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS/Properties/vertical-align